# Mapping a JSON key value pair to HashMap

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

I am trying to map a key value pair in json, `recipient_status` below, to a `Map<String, String>` object. All fields get parsed correctly, except this one. Is there another way I should parse a key value pair?

I am sending the following JSON string:

```
{
  "id": "layer:///messages/940de862-3c96-11e4-baad-164230d1df67",
  "parts": [
    {
      "id": "layer:///messages/940de862-3c96-11e4-baad-164230d1df67/parts/0",
      "mime_type": "text/plain",
      "body": "This is the message."
    }
  ],
  "sent_at": "2014-09-09T04:44:47+00:00",
  "recipient_status": {
    "layer:///identities/777": "sent",
    "layer:///identities/999": "read",
    "layer:///identities/111": "delivered",
    "layer:///identities/1234": "read"
  },
  "position": 120709792
}
```

To my Java Sprint Boot backend

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/")
public String conversationCreated(@RequestBody Message message) {
}
```

And try to parse it into the following object:

```
@Data
public class Message {
    private String id;

    private List<Part> parts;

    private LocalDateTime sentAt;

    private Map<String, String> recipientStatus;

    private Long position;
}
```

Comment: try private Map<String, List<String>> recipientStatus;

Comment: Try and replace the map object with ``` JsonObject ``` and see if it works

Comment: @vikaskumar, that doesn't work either. recipientStatus stays null.

Comment: Same for your solution @mehdimaick.

Comment: replace the recipientStatus with Object, and check it it's null, or replace it with Map<String, Object> and test again .

Comment: you got to do it manually by traversing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably with `recipientStatus` property name. There is no match between the name in the `Message` object and JSON. There are multiple ways to solve this problem:

1. As @ddarellis suggested, rename property either in your Java class or in JSON so they will match.
2. Mark Java property with `@JsonProperty` annotation

   ```
   public class Message {
       @JsonProperty("recipient_status")
       private Map<String, String> recipientStatus;
   }
   ```
3. Set `PropertyNamingStrategy` on the deserializer to `SNAKE_CASE` either by modifying `ObjectMapper`

   ```
   new ObjectMapper().setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
   ```

   or with the `JsonNaming` annotation

   ```
   @JsonNaming(PropertyNamingStrategy.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
   public class Message {
       private Map<String, String> recipientStatus;
   }
   ```

I think that in your case the third option is preferable. You already have two properties in this naming strategy, and it would be easier to add new fields without thinking that you need to add another `JsonProperty`. Also, this strategy can be set globally for the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is at `recipient_status`, you should change it to `recipientStatus`. Your JSON should match the POJO variable name. No need to do something special to made a `HashMap`.

Answer (score -1):

If u r not sure about the problem, pls use http://json2csharp.com/ website to check your generated json class as below:
[image]

See what? The json totally foos my generator and it can't convert the json.

So here, you need to change the recipient_status part in your json fragment.

**Suggestion:**

Change the recipient_status to below:

```
 "recipient_status": {
     "sent":"layer:///identities/777",
     "read":["layer:///identities/999","layer:///identities/1234"],
     "delivered":"layer:///identities/111",
 }
```

And the generator from json2csharp.com will work well:
[image]

Think that you need to do some correction on the generated class.
Hope that helps.